# fit a number into the range if if chained

Tags: c#, .net, if-statement, switch-statement, case

I have a total variable
and I have a range of 250 out of 250
I need to know in which range is the variable, but in a range of 15250 would have to do more than 61 if chained, has another way to eliminate this repetition of ifs?
Thanks for the help.
example

```
 public void ValidTravel(int Traveled)
 {
    int total = 15250
    int range = 250   

     if (Traveled>= 1 && Traveled<= 250)
        {                
           return 250;
        }

     if (Traveled>= 251 && Traveled<= 500)
        {                
           return 500;
        }

     if (Traveled>= 501 && Traveled<= 750)
        {                
           return 750;
        }

     if (Traveled>= 751 && Traveled<= 1000)
        {                
           return 1000;
        }

}
```

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You may wish to do some research into the modulus operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use those code to detect range and perform round up by X factor which is as per your requirement

```
public int ValidTravel(int Traveled)
    {
        int total = 15250;
        int range = 250;
        double RetrunResult = 0;

        if (Traveled <= 0 || Traveled > total) // return error code -1 if Input value Traveled is not in range 1-15250
        { RetrunResult = -1; }
        else if (Traveled % range == 0) // use mod to cover value 250 , 500 , 750 , 1000....
        { RetrunResult = Traveled; } 
        else if (Traveled % 250 > 0)   // for those value that cant cover by mod , we will use divide value
        {
            double DivFactor = Traveled / 250;
            if (DivFactor >= 1)
            { RetrunResult = (Math.Ceiling(DivFactor) + 1 )* 250; } //  we know value greater then 250 so we will use ceiling function to force round up
            else if (DivFactor < 1)
            { RetrunResult = 250; }   // we know value is between 1-250 , so we will make RetrunResult = 250
        }


        return Convert.ToInt32(RetrunResult);


    }
```